# Disable CMD+Tab application switcher

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos-carbon, hotkeys

I'm trying to disable the <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> application switcher, so that my application can register that hotkey. I'm looking for something that applications like **Witch** and **LiteSwitch X** are able to do (i.e. allow users to use <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> as the hotkey for my application).

How are they able to do that?

Comment: That would be a rather user-unfriendly thing to do, unless you have a *very* good reason for doing it. You should also make sure that the user can disable this "feature" via Preferences.

Comment: I'm doing it for the same reason Witch is doing it, to implement my own application switcher. Of course, it will work only if the user chooses this hotkey in the first place.

Comment: Did you implement this? Can you show the code?